# Does constrained EM algorithm work with bad initial inputs?

Tags: optimization, expectation-maximization, constrained-regression

When trying to perform **constrained** optimization using EM algorithm, does EM work if the **initial** solution (x0) **violates** the constraints?

Comment: Do you have a specific problem class in mind to which you are applying EM, as well as the type of constraints, and algorithm/software for performing it?  The answer to your question may depend on these. For the answer to be yes, your EM algorithm implementation may need some kind of feasibility step, in order to get from your infeasible initial solution (i.e., solution which violates one or more constraints), to a feasible solution, from which point the main optimization can proceed.  How good the resulting feasible initial solution would be is another matter.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone My problem is that it's very hard to get an initializtion that meets the constraints, but it's easy to get an otherwise reasonable initialization. So, bringing the initialization to meet the constraints **before** running EM isn't practical. M-step updates equations were derived to meet the constraints. Question is what'd happen when this is run on a non-compliant initial values?

Comment: it's difficult to give specific advice because you haven't told us what problem you are trying to solve, and what type (form) of constraInts you have, such as linear, nonlinear inequality, nonlinear equality, semidefinite, or whatever. A common approach is to solve an auxiliary optimization problem of some type whose solution will result in a feasible solution to your original problem. Then you can then use that as the starting point.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Ideally constraints are equality non-linear: I need that the sum of some probabilities calculated in E-step sum up to a fixed value, while increasing the log-likelihood. E.g., a mixture of Gaussians with sum of probabilities calculated by the mixture over some data set be constant.

Comment: Solve the nonlinear equality constraints with a numerical solver for systems of nonlinear equations or as a nonlinear least squares problem (you may need a starting point for that problem as well, but of course it need not be feasible). Presuming you get a feasible solution to your original problem, use that as the initial point for the main EM algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

In order to run constrained EM when you do not have a feasible initial (starting) solution, i.e., a solution which satisfies the constraints, I recommend the following.

Formulate and solve an auxiliary problem whose solution provides you a feasible initial solution to the constrained problem you wish to solve by EM.

In the case of the constraints consisting of a system of nonlinear equalities (equations), you should numerically solve this system of nonlinear equations by using either:

1) a numerical solver for systems of nonlinear equations or

2) formulate and solve as a nonlinear least squares problem (objective function is the sum of squares of differences between left-hand and right-hand sides of the nonlinear equations), and "success" occurs if a solution is found which is within numerical tolerance of being zero

In either approach, you may need to provide a starting point for that problem as well, but of course it need not be feasible. Presuming that you get a (successful) solution to either of the above approaches, that will be a feasible solution to your original problem, and can be used as the initial point for the main EM algorithm. If you can not find a successful solution to either of the above approaches, then try a different starting value to feed into them, or it could be that the constraints are inconsistent, i.e., there is no feasible solution.

Comment: @qwer1304  Have you tried this out?